# Immutable.js not copying object

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I've been testing Immutable.js and the following code sets a key to an object in an Immutable Map. After the key has been set to the object, the original object is mutated. As you can see by running the code below, when getting the object and logging it from the Immutable.js Map, the object in the Immutable.js map is referencing the original mutated objected.

Isn't the purpose of Immutable.js to return a new immutable copy each time new data is set? I would have expected a deep clone?

```
const Immutable = require('immutable');

const testObj = { id: 'a' };
console.log('TEST OBJECT');
console.log(testObj); // { id: 'a' }

const newMap = Immutable.Map();
const newMap2 = newMap.set('a', testObj);
console.log('AFTER INITIAL IMMUTABLE SET');
console.log(newMap2.get('a')); // { id: 'a' }

testObj.id = 'z';
console.log('AFTER MUTATING ID IN TESTOBJ');
console.log(testObj); // { id: 'z' }
console.log(newMap2.get('a')); // { id: 'z' }
```

Comment: What you need to test is logging both console.log(newMap.get('a')) which results in { id: 'a' }
 and console.log(newMap2.get('a')) which logs { id: 'z' }
testObj is mutable but the newMap and newMap2 are immutable. You  are mutating the testObj which is outside the scope of maps.

Comment: So Immutable.js is the same using `Object.assign` or `{ ...obj }`? You get a single level clone but all of nested levels maintain their original references?

Comment: @Kainan You're using it incorrectly. I recommend you read some ImmutableJs tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `newMap2.id` to the reference object `testObj`, not the value of `testObj`

If you wanted to set `newMap` to the value of `testObj` you would do:

```
const newMap = Immutable.Map({a: Immutable.Map(testObj));
```

or use `fromJS` to deep clone (see https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS)

```
const newMap = Immutable.fromJS({a: testObj));
```

and then get the value using toJS if you wanted a standard js object (see https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/toJS)

```
newMap.get('a').toJS();
```

Comment: That sets the key to 'id' and the value to 'a'.

Comment: Updated... the reason it doesn't deeply clone is because the data inside of `a` is a reference to `testObj` change this by converting `testObj` to immutable